# Regular expression help

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to create a regex in Python 3 that matches 7 characters (eg. >AB0012) separated by an unknown number of characters then matching another 6 characters(eg. aaabbb or bbbaaa). My input string might look like this:

`>AB0012xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>CD00192aaabbblllllllllllllllllllllyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyybbbaaayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy>ZP0199000000000000000000012mmmm3m4mmmmmmmmxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaaabbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`

This is the regex that I have come up with:

```
matches = re.findall(r'(>.{7})(aaabbb|bbbaaa)', mystring)  
print(matches)
```

The output I am trying to product would look like this:

```
[('>CD00192', 'aaabbb'), ('>CD00192', 'bbbaaa'), ('>ZP01990', 'aaabbb')]
```

I read through the Python documentation, but I couldn't find how to match an unknown distance between two portions of a regex. Is there some sort of wildcard character that would allow me to complete my regex? Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT:
If I use `*?` in my code like this:

```
mystring = str(input("Paste promoters here: "))
matches = re.findall(r'(>.{7})*?(aaabbb|bbbaaa)', mystring)
print(matches)
```

My output looks like this:
[('>CD00192', 'aaabbb'), ('', 'bbbaaa'), ('', 'aaabbb')]

*The second and third items in the list are missing the >CD00192 and >ZP01990, respectively. How can I have the regex include these characters in the list?

Comment: As the `aaabbb` pattern is encountered before the `bbbaaa` one, why the second pair shouldn't be `('>CD00192', 'aaabbb')`? Is it because the distance must be at least 1, or is it because you forbid multiple matches of the same substring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a code that gives also the positions.

Here's the simple version of this code:

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

ch = '>AB0012xxxxaaaaaaaaaaaa'\
     '>CD00192aaabbbllyybbbaaayyyuubbbaaaggggaaabbb'\
     '>ZP0199000012mmmm3m4mmmxxxxaaabbbaaaaaaaaaaaaa'\
     '>QD1547zzzzzzzzjjjiii'\
     '>SE457895ffffaaabbbbbbbgjhgjgjhgjhgbbbbbaaa'


print ch,'\n'

regx = re.compile('((?<=>)(.{7})[^>]*(?:aaabbb|bbbaaa)[^>]*?)(?=>|\Z)')
rag = re.compile('aaabbb|bbbaaa')

dic = OrderedDict()


# Finding the result
for mat in regx.finditer(ch):
    chunk,head = mat.groups()
    headstart = mat.start()
    dic[(headstart,head)] = [(headstart+six.start(),six.start(),six.group())
                             for six in rag.finditer(chunk)]


# Diplaying the result
for (headstart,head),li in dic.iteritems():
    print '{:>10} {}'.format(headstart,head)
    for x in li:
        print '{0[0]:>10} {0[1]:>6} {0[2]}'.format(x)
```

result

```
>AB0012xxxxaaaaaaaaaaaa>CD00192aaabbbllyybbbaaayyyuubbbaaaggggaaabbb>ZP0199000012mmmm3m4mmmxxxxaaabbbaaaaaaaaaaaaa>QD1547zzzzzzzzjjjiii>SE457895ffffaaabbbbbbbgjhgjgjhgjhgbbbbbaaa 

        24 CD00192
        31      8 aaabbb
        41     18 bbbaaa
        52     29 bbbaaa
        62     39 aaabbb
        69 ZP01990
        95     27 aaabbb
       136 SE45789
       148     13 aaabbb
       172     37 bbbaaa
```

The same code, in a functional manner, using generators :

```
import re
from itertools import imap
from collections import OrderedDict

ch = '>AB0012xxxxaaaaaaaaaaaa'\
     '>CD00192aaabbbllyybbbaaayyyuubbbaaaggggaaabbb'\
     '>ZP0199000012mmmm3m4mmmxxxxaaabbbaaaaaaaaaaaaa'\
     '>QD1547zzzzzzzzjjjiii'\
     '>SE457895ffffaaabbbbbbbgjhgjgjhgjhgbbbbbaaa'


print ch,'\n'

regx = re.compile('((?<=>)(.{7})[^>]*(?:aaabbb|bbbaaa)[^>]*?)(?=>|\Z)')
rag = re.compile('aaabbb|bbbaaa')

gen = ((mat.groups(),mat.start()) for mat in regx.finditer(ch)) 


dic = OrderedDict(((headstart,head),
                   [(headstart+six.start(),six.start(),six.group())
                    for six in rag.finditer(chunk)])
                  for (chunk,head),headstart in gen)


print '\n'.join('{:>10} {}'.format(headstart,head)+'\n'+\
                '\n'.join(imap('{0[0]:>10} {0[1]:>6} {0[2]}'.format,li))
                for (headstart,head),li in dic.iteritems())
```

.

### EDIT

I measured the execution's times.

For each code I measured the creation of the dictionary and the displaying separately.

The code using generators (the second) is 7.4 times more rapid to display the result ( 0.020 seconds) than the other one (0.148 seconds)

But surprisingly for me, the code with generators takes 47 % more time (0.000718 seconds) than the other (0.000489 seconds) to compute the dictionary.

.

### EDIT 2

Another way to do:

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import imap

ch = '>AB0012xxxxaaaaaaaaaaaa'\
     '>CD00192aaabbbllyybbbaaayyyuubbbaaaggggaaabbb'\
     '>ZP0199000012mmmm3m4mmmxxxxaaabbbaaaaaaaaaaaaa'\
     '>QD1547zzzzzzzzjjjiii'\
     '>SE457895ffffaaabbbbbbbgjhgjgjhgjhgbbbbbaaa'


print ch,'\n'


regx = re.compile('((?<=>).{7})|(aaabbb|bbbaaa)')

def collect(ch):
    li = []
    dic = OrderedDict()

    gen = ( (x.start(),x.group(1),x.group(2)) for x in regx.finditer(ch))
    for st,g1,g2 in gen:
        if g1:
            if li:
                dic[(stprec,g1prec)] = li
            li,stprec,g1prec = [],st,g1
        elif g2:
            li.append((st,g2))
    if li:
        dic[(stprec,g1prec)] = li
    return dic


dic = collect(ch)

print '\n'.join('{:>10} {}'.format(headstart,head)+'\n'+\
                '\n'.join(imap('{0[0]:>10}   {0[1]}'.format,li))
                for (headstart,head),li in dic.iteritems())
```

result

```
>AB0012xxxxaaaaaaaaaaaa>CD00192aaabbbllyybbbaaayyyuubbbaaaggggaaabbb>ZP0199000012mmmm3m4mmmxxxxaaabbbaaaaaaaaaaaaa>QD1547zzzzzzzzjjjiii>SE457895ffffaaabbbbbbbgjhgjgjhgjhgbbbbbaaa 

        24 CD00192
        31   aaabbb
        41   bbbaaa
        52   bbbaaa
        62   aaabbb
        69 ZP01990
        95   aaabbb
       136 SE45789
       148   aaabbb
       172   bbbaaa
```

This code compute dic in 0.00040 seconds and displays it in 0.0321 seconds

.

### EDIT 3

To answer to your question, you have no other possibility than keeping each current value among 'CD00192','ZP01990','SE45789' etc under a name (I don't like to say *"in a variable"* in Python, because there are no variables in Python. But you can read *"under a name"* as if I had written *"in a variable"* )

And for that, you must use **finditer()**

Here's the code for this solution:

```
import re

ch = '>AB0012xxxxaaaaaaaaaaaa'\
     '>CD00192aaabbbllyybbbaaayyyuubbbaaaggggaaabbb'\
     '>ZP0199000012mmmm3m4mmmxxxxaaabbbaaaaaaaaaaaaa'\
     '>QD1547zzzzzzzzjjjiii'\
     '>SE457895ffffaaabbbbbbbgjhgjgjhgjhgbbbbbaaa'


print ch,'\n'

regx = re.compile('(>.{7})|(aaabbb|bbbaaa)')

matches = []
for mat in regx.finditer(ch):
    g1,g2= mat.groups()
    if g1:
        head = g1
    else:
        matches.append((head,g2))

print matches
```

result

```
>AB0012xxxxaaaaaaaaaaaa>CD00192aaabbbllyybbbaaayyyuubbbaaaggggaaabbb>ZP0199000012mmmm3m4mmmxxxxaaabbbaaaaaaaaaaaaa>QD1547zzzzzzzzjjjiii>SE457895ffffaaabbbbbbbgjhgjgjhgjhgbbbbbaaa 

[('>CD00192', 'aaabbb'), ('>CD00192', 'bbbaaa'), ('>CD00192', 'bbbaaa'), ('>CD00192', 'aaabbb'), ('>ZP01990', 'aaabbb'), ('>SE45789', 'aaabbb'), ('>SE45789', 'bbbaaa')]
```

My preceding codes are more complicated because they catch the positions and gather the values 'aaabbb' and 'bbbaaa' of one header among 'CD00192','ZP01990','SE45789' etc in a list.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. I am using Python 3 and I tried your code. I get an error for `from itertools import imap` "cannot import name imap. Do you have any idea what the problem could be? Thanks again.

Comment: @dr.bunsen In Python 3, the function that does the same as the Python 2'**imap** is named simply **map** and is  built-in

Comment: Thanks again, this was a huge help. I learned a ton. I appreciate you taking the time to explain things so thoroughly.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a non regular expression approach. Split on ">" (your data will start from 2nd element onwards), then since you don't care what those 7 characters are, so start checking from 8th character onwards till 14th character.

```
>>> string=""" AB0012xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa>CD00192aaabbblllllllllllllllllllllyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyybbbaaayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy>ZP0199000000000000000000012mmmm3m4mmmmmmmmxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaaabbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa""" 
>>> for i in string.split(">")[1:]:
...   if i[7:13] in ["aaabbb","bbbaaa"]:
...     print ">" + i[:13]
...
>CD00192aaabbb
```

Comment: Awesome. This is a cool idea. I am using Python 3 and I am not sure how to format the output line. I would love not to have to use regex expressions! Will this only match the first "aaabbb" or "bbbaaa"? If a > element is followed by multiple "aaabbb" or "bbbaaa" elements will this code catch more than one second element? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

zero or more characters can be matched using `*`, so `a*` would match `""`, `"a"`, `"aa"` etc. `+` matches one or more character.

You will perhaps want to make the quantifier (`+` or `*`) lazy by using `+?` or `*?` as well.

See [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for more details.

Comment: bergmark thanks for the help. the '*?' helped but my output is still missing character matches (see EDIT above).

Comment: You are now matching `(>.{7})` zero or more times lazily. You probably wanted `(>{7}).*?` to match `>`, 7 chars, and then zero or  more other chars? Also, doing something like `(.){3}` won't capture all 3 matches into the capture group, rather it will just save the last match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> r1 = re.findall(r'(>.{7})[^>]*?(aaabbb)', s)  
>>> r2 = re.findall(r'(>.{7})[^>]*?(bbbaaa)', s)  
>>> r1 + r2
[('>CD00192', 'aaabbb'), ('>ZP01990', 'aaabbb'), ('>CD00192', 'bbbaaa'), ('>ZP01990',     'bbbaaa')]
```

Comment: Sorry, I just now saw this. I tried a similar approach to yours at first. My output results are different though. I get: `[('>CD00192', 'aaabbb'), ('', 'aaabbb'), ('', 'bbbaaa'), ('',     'bbbaaa')]`          It seems to drop the first half of the character match?